# Create Dataframes columns with values from another DF and update matched in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, where-clause, transpose

My data looks like this.
df1:
[image: DF1]

df2:
[image: DF2]

expected output:

[image: Expected Output DF3:]

Can anyone help with the functions in R if available.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library(reshape2)

```
  name var1
1    a    7
2    b    8
3    c    8

df2
  name language
1    a        c
2    a        q
3    a        s
4    b     java
5    b        k
6    c        r
7    c        t
8    c        c

df3 <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2 %>% count(name, language)
df3 <- dcast(df3, name + var1 ~ language, value.var = "n", fun.aggregate = sum)

df3
  name var1 c java k q r s t
1    a    7 1    0 0 1 0 1 0
2    b    8 0    1 1 0 0 0 0
3    c    8 1    0 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 1000+ columns in DF1 and millions of rows of data. Tested ok on sample data but is there a way to retain all the columns in DF3 instead of saying "name + var1 + var2 + var3

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer:

```
> df1 %>% inner_join(df2 %>% count(name, language) %>%  
+                      pivot_wider(names_from = language, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
+                                                               relocate(c(c, java, r, q, k, t, s)))
Joining, by = "name"
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  name   var1     c  java     r     q     k     t     s
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 a         7     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
2 b         8     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
3 c         8     1     0     1     0     0     1     0
>
```

Comment: I guess giving all the values in "relocate(c(c, java, r, q, k, t, s)" would be very tedious.

Comment: It's upto you to relocate or not. I just wanted to bring the columns ordering the way you showed. You may drop that relocate part if you are not particular about ordering.